# Have error when try to use xgoogle library in code

Tags: python-3.3

Have error with xgoogle library

**When I tried to use this code:**

```
from xgoogle.search import GoogleSearch, SearchError
try:
  gs = GoogleSearch("quick")
  gs.results_per_page = 50
  results = gs.get_results()
  for res in results:
    print (res.title.encode("utf8"))
    print (res.desc.encode("utf8"))
    print (res.url.encode("utf8"))
```

**I get this error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/s.sorokin/PycharmProjects/hh.ru/xgoogle.py", line 1, in <module>
    from xgoogle.search import GoogleSearch, SearchError
  File "C:\Users\s.sorokin\PycharmProjects\hh.ru\xgoogle\search.py", line 124
    raise SearchError, "Wrong parameter to first_indexed_in_previous: %s" % (str(interval))
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Ok, when i'm try to use python 2.7, code work fine
Who now how i can use this library on ver 3.7?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned on the library's website, `xgoogle` was only built as a "quick hack". From what you mention, it looks like it's written in Python 2. You therefore will not be able to run it in Python 3, unless you rewrite it.

If you want to use Python 3, you'll likely have to find a library that supports it.